# node's exec() not working because of a space in the URI name

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, path, escaping

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var cmd = 'C:\\Users\\Johnny Cash\\Desktop\\executeme.exe'

exec(cmd, function(e, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(stdout);
  console.log(stderr);
});
```

> 'C:\Users\Johnny' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This has got to be the newbiest question ever, but how do I escape these paths with spaces on windows? It's cuts off at the space and nothing I do (single or double escapes beforehand) seems to do the trick. Does `exec()` do some formatting I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) treats any spaces in the `command` parameter string as argument separators, so you need to double-quote the whole path to have it all treated as the path to the command to run:

```
var cmd = '"C:\\Users\\Johnny Cash\\Desktop\\executeme.exe"'
```

But it's probably cleaner just to use [`execFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) instead, as its `file` parameter is always treated as the file path, with a separate `args` parameter. Then you should be able to omit the double-quote wrapping. `execFile` is a bit leaner anyway as it doesn't execute a subshell like `exec` does.

Comment: What if I need to pass an argument to `exec` which is another long string with spaces?

Comment: @dsp_099 Double quote the argument separately or use `execFile` and pass the argument in its own array parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to scape the space char from the URI by using `^` (caret) char:

```
var cmd = 'C:\\Users\\Johnny^ Cash\\Desktop\\executeme.exe'
```

Comment: This works where everything else fails.
We tried double escape.
We tried %ProgramFiles%
We tried everything we could and every single time we got a "C:\Program" is blabla.

BUT THIS.
This saved our day.